# Add an option to offer bounties from (cash) donations

Tags: feature-request, bounty

**Context.** It is currently possible to award [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to your own questions and questions of others. Bounties can be used to attract more attention to questions and are an extremely helpful tool in getting experts to look at questions, and solve them.

**Problem.** Some users do not have enough reputation to offer bounties. I do not have the extra bandwidth to participate in answering questions to raise my reputation, at least not to the level of devotion it seems to take to raise the score.

**Proposed feature.** I am in a position, and willing, to make a donation. Hence my proposal:

- Allow users to donate to Stack Overflow, or the Stack Exchange network in general.
- Award users *donation points* (similar to reputation, but a separate counter).
- Allow users to offer bounties using these donation points. The donation points cannot be used for other purposes and will not unlock privileges. They are fully separated from reputation.

**Miscellaneous ideas.** I toyed with the idea that the donation points would be visible and indicate whether I've donated. That has both good and bad consequences.

Comment: A bounty is not a donation. A bounty is just a paid commercial for more attention on the question.

Comment: In case there is confusion. Right now, where do the points come from for a bounty?

Comment: From the users's reputation. And that can't (or shouldn't) be bought.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pay with real money for getting a bounty on your question? I find this proposal confusing.

Comment: I agree. I'm suggesting that there is a second bean counter value that the bounty can be subtracted from. This second bean counter value is increased by a donation. This bean counter can be kept hidden.

Comment: @D-Klotz Can I take a stab at (heavily) editing your question? I think I can phrase it differently to make it more clear. You can always [edit] it afterwards, or even rollback to your original revision.

Comment: I don't think I like the idea of paying for it. Why should the company get money for the answer that is provided by volunteers? And wouldn't that end in a two-class community?

Comment: Yes, editing the question might help, because there is no "bean counter" and there are no "donations". That makes it different to understand what you actually mean.

Comment: @BDL I don't think OP means donations with real money, but rather donations as a synonym for the reputation paid bounties.

Comment: Sorry. This would all be "new" features. The person who answers the question gets reputation that I payed for by a donation. SO I guess if that is something that goes against the grain of the community...

Comment: @Tom, I think they mean real money donations, to buy rep to use for a bounty. And rep should not be bought.

Comment: @yivi.  Yes real money.

Comment: @Tom: I think exactly that is meant: You pay with real money to get a bounty on your question.

Comment: Oh please no ... do not want.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check if this is what you meant, @D-Klotz.

Comment: You probably would be much better off to offer money directly to someone with knowledge of the subject... The amount of money for initial reputation points should be significant - let's say one spends half an hour on solid answer that just gets one upvote - so for minimal bounty you need ~2.5 hours which for reasonable US contractor rate is $200-300...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Nope

The moment we make it possible to "buy" reputation, it loses any value it had.

Comment: You misunderstand. This would NOT affect reputation, it would indirectly give someone else reputation if they can answer the question correctly.

Comment: My edit to the question clarifies that these donations would not buy reputation.

Comment: It would affect reputation in a two-fold way: first, logically it would affect the bounty's winner rep. (Reputation bought, even if for someone different than the payer). Secondly, you'd get "publicity" that could garner you votes in your question, and you'd get that publicity for money (instead of paying via rep, like everyone else).

Comment: It'd be very similar. Another counter of "This was useful" points, but in this case bought instead of _earned_.

Comment: @D-Klotz You can easily affect your own reputation by using a sock-puppet account, buying reputation for that and then create a bounty question which your main acc answers.

Comment: @Tom Just playing devil's advocate here: "You can easily affect your own reputation by using a sock-puppet account and upvoting all your main questions and answers." My point being, both cases would be seen as fraud. Same with voting rings, et cetera.

Comment: Why would we need additional, harder to police, fraud avenues? Which would also imply _buying rep_, which is something patently undesirable?

Comment: @Justastudent There is a ___big___ difference between upvoting a lot of posts of another user (your main acc for example) and buying reputation to ask one single question and never use that account again. It's hard to detect fraud when you only have one interaction with the other account.

Comment: I'm going to respectfully ask for a self evaluation here. Please make sure you are against this idea because it breaks the spirit of the site versus a hit against pride at having a high reputation (that you rightfully have earned).

Comment: I do not have a high reputation. I am **firmly** against this idea.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I admit that I fail to see how it would really break the economy of the site but perhaps after more tea I'll see it.

Comment: Keep in mind that all answers are provided by volunteers. If you want to pay for getting things done, then ask a specialist and he will tell you his price. Why would I want someone to pay SO in order to get faster answers from a volunteer? This would only lead to a two class community: Those who pay and those who don't.

Comment: Another problem I see is that this steers the community even more away from general and reusable questions to the "help me solve my problem for me" questions. The general misunderstanding seems to be that you even get better answers just by attaching a bounty. If you really want better answers, write a better and more interesting question. Crappy questions will get crappy answers, not matter how much you pay for it.

Comment: @BDL how would anyone know the difference? If you are really that concerned, make it so you can't make a donation until your normal rep is above XXX. Then it will take someone really "OCD" to observe that your REP didn't go down when you created a bounty.

Comment: @D-Klotz: You failed to see my point: I wouldn't be willing to answer questions for free if you have to pay SO to get your question answered.

Comment: Again, sorry for the redundancy. How would "you" know I payed to have a bounty?

Comment: What would it change if I know or don't know. I invest my time here for free, I wouldn't be willing to work for free if there are people paying someone else for it. I think that already the option of paying for it will drive volunteers away.

Comment: Ok. I see your point. I'm sure others will have your mindset a well. I looked at it like this is a way to help a site pay the bills and "you" if you decide to answer, get a normal reputation boost from someone like me that doesn't have the time to invest like you.  I do see your point. Obviously this won't go anywhere. Thanks for your time btw :)

Comment: @D-Klotz another BIG problem here is that.... we heavily moderate questions and answers here.... Once someone starts to pay SO for their question.... closing or deleting it can't really be done, right? So..... Someone who pays to bounty low-quality/off-topic questions would pollute the site...

Comment: @Patrice Personally I wouldn't change any of the rules. If I write a stupid question and after a couple of days 'pay cash' for creating a bounty, it will either live or die as normal? Are there special deletion rules for a question with a bounty? If so then yes, I agree that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @D-Klotz a question with a bounty currently cannot be closed, deleted, or anything, as long as the bounty is on. The only way to moderate such a question is to flag a diamond moderator who will remove the bounty. You can be SURE that there would be meta post about "I PAY FOR THIS QUESTION, ANSWER IT!!!!!". We already get such entitled posts, WITHOUT any money involved...

Comment: Ok I didn't know that. Lets delete this idea then. I'm all for deleting it.

Comment: @D-Klotz: That's not strictly necessary. Downvoted meta questions can often be a valuable duplicate target.

Comment: @D-Klotz no need. Since it's already answered, your question can serve as a reference for whoever wants to ask a similar feature and does their research beforehand :).